# load n natural number then load another natural number and print all the digits of that number in the number system with n digits

Tags: c++

load "n" natural number then load another natural number and print all the digits of that number in the number system with n digits?

I have no example of a task because it is not clear to me what the profit should be if I type 13 and 4 for example what should I print....

Comment: Are you asking what a [positional numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) is? I guess that is what the question is referring to.

Comment: maybe that’s what it refers to

Comment: Is this for a course that you are taking? Perhaps you should ask your instructor for more clarification if so. I'm afraid we won't really be able to help you without a clearer picture of what it is you're trying to accomplish, especially if you yourself are unsure of the problem.

Comment: hello, i bought some book for learning c ++ for beginners so unfortunately i have no instructor ..
I'm from Croatian so maybe my translation is not very clear ...
but never mind thank you for trying to help